# Controlling Image Size with External TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I am building a groupplot using extikzpicture to externalize the graphics so that I can later just include them when I submit the paper for publication.  I would like to reduce the size of the final groupplot.  I could probably work this out on my own, but I'm working with severely compromised internet access at the moment, so it's difficult to research anything....even in posting this question, I can't get the full editor to load...hope I can make this look decent with markdown....

The code below (which is not an MWE) is the offending bit

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{extikzpicture}[runs=2]{fig5}
    \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={group size=2 by 2,
                                     height=10cm,
                                     width=10cm,
                                     group name = fig5_plots,
                         xlabels at=edge bottom,
                         ylabels at=edge left
                                    },
                        xlabel = {\footnotesize $\rho$},
                        ylabel = {\footnotesize $\gamma$},
                                    %view={0}{90},
                                    colorbar horizontal,
                                    colorbar to name=ContourColorbar,
                                    colormap/blackwhite,
                                    y tick label style={
                                        /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                        fixed,
                                        fixed zerofill,
                                        precision=1,
                                        /tikz/.cd
                                    },
                                    x tick label style={
                                        /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                        fixed,
                                        fixed zerofill,
                                        precision=0,
                                        /tikz/.cd
                                    }]
                        \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize +Resources}, z buffer=sort]
                                        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,mesh,black] file {Reactive_ComeAndGo_Surface.txt};
                                        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite, opacity=0.8] file {PlusReactive_DecreasingAlpha_Surface.txt};
                                    \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize ++Resources}, z buffer=sort]
                                        \addplot3[surf, mesh,black] file {Reactive_ComeAndGo_Surface.txt};
                                        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite, opacity=0.8] file {PlusPlusReactive_DecreasingAlpha_Surface.txt};
                                     %\nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize +Resources Delta},view={0}{90},]
                                        \nextgroupplot[view={0}{90},]
                                         \addplot3[surf, shader=interp] file {Plus_Reactive_Delta_Surface.txt};
                                     %\nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize ++Resources Delta},view={0}{90},]
                                        \nextgroupplot[view={0}{90},]
                                            \addplot3[surf, shader=interp] file {PlusPlus_Reactive_Delta_Surface.txt};
    \end{groupplot}
    \node (fig5_Legend) at ($(fig5_plots c1r2.center)!0.5!(fig5_plots c2r2.center)-(0,4.5cm)$){\ref{ContourColorbar}};
\end{extikzpicture}
\caption{Reactive $\alpha$ Starting at Upper Bound}
\label{ReactiveDecreasing}
\end{figure}
```

You'll note the lines

```
height=10cm,
width=10cm,
```

in the groupstyle...they're the problem.  If I remove those two lines, it compiles fine and produces an image, just one that is larger than I want.

[image]

Include those lines, and I get an error because there is no external image.  When I look through the log file for that specific image, I find

Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/group/height', to whi
ch you passed '10cm', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

With my crappy internet access, I can't really search for anything.  I have the pgfplot manual, which shows using the height and width keys in the groupstyle for a tikzpicture groupplot, so I assumed it would be the same for an extikzpicture, but evidently not.

Comment: where does the `extikzpicture` come from?

Comment: @percusse In the preamble `\usepackage{pgfplots}`  `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh!

I misread the documentation.  The height and width keys do not go in the group style.

On page 391 of the pgfplots manual I had seen this line

```
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2},height=3cm,width=3cm]
```

And somehow my brain saw height and width inside the closing }, not outside.  Move those keys out of the group style and you're golden.

I need to sleep more :)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use something similar to your solution, and I realized that using `extikzpicture` has some limitations compare to the standard `tikzpicture`.

For instance, say I define a macro for my figure height in the preamble
`\newcommand{\fheight}{5cm}`; 
if I now want to use it as the height of my groupplots in a standard `tikzpicture`, I can simply write `height=\fheight` as an option of the `grouplot` environment. However, if I do the same within the `extikzpicture`, I get the error

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \pgfplots@height ->\fheight

No idea of the reason why.